# Remove forward view from history in ionic

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, hybrid-mobile-app

I need to remove a particular view from the history, specifically the forwardView.
My situation/navigation is this:
**ion1 -> ion3 ->** (stateParam A sent to the view) **ion5 -> ion3 ->** (stateParam B sent to the view) **ion5 -> ion7 -> ion5**, where I end with the previous ion5 view (with stateParam A) from the history.
I know that if I use a cached view on ion5 this problem doesn't appear, but I can't use cached view here for some other reasons.

What I want to do is to remove the forwardView (ion5) from the histories stack first time I go back to ion3, so a new ion5* (it will get other number, but for reference) view with the correct stateParam is saved in history. Then when I navigate to ion7 and go back, the right ion5* is recovered from history.

I think removeBackView doesn't apply here nor location replace.

Answer (score 0):

I realize this question is almost a year old but I just ran into a similar problem myself so I thought I would answer it. I recommend using `$ionicView.afterLeave` and then checking which view you have arrived at with `$ionicHistory.currentStateName()`.

Once your condition has been met, you can delete the forward view (as well as back views) using `$ionicHistory.clearHistory()`. This will not affect `$stateParams`. Sadly there is no way to only remove the forward view, you will have to remove back views as well.

I'll try to write an example for your situation:

In ion5's controller:

```
$scope.$on('$ionicView.afterLeave', function(event, data) {
    if ($ionicHistory.currentStateName() === 'ion3') {
        $ionicHistory.clearHistory();
    }
});
```